# Sparse Varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 table with a Varchar(max) field that is rarely used. 
Would it make more sense to move that field into another table and point to this table?

Or if a Varchar(max) field contains null, does it not take up a whole lot of room?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. SQL Server already uses a separate allocation unit for BLOB types, see [Table and Index Organization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). A NULL value occupies only one bit in a row, see [Anatomy of a Record](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/).

You will waste more space by creating a separate table and will be significantly more expensive to check if the column is NULL or has a value. Besides the column values may be optimized and pulled in-row for small values, if they fit, offering significant faster access. Overall, don't try to micro-optimize something that the engine is already pushing the envelope to make it as efficient as possible....

If the *table* is sparse (meaning it has many (hundreds, thousands) columns from which many are NULL on each row) then you could use [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Remus.  I used that word sparse on purpose.  I'm glad to know that in my case, simpler is better.

Answer (score 3):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224016(v=sql.80).aspx :

> The varchar data type is a variable-length data type. Values shorter
>   than the size of the column are not right-padded to the size of the
>   colum

varchar contains just length + content.

A nullable field uses an extra bit to store the null/non-null state so no extra space is taken up in the record itself.